# Decimal to binary in 32 bit assembly (IA-32)

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32, x86

Hello i am trying to make a code that will transfer a decimal number in range of <0; 65 535> to binary, and so far my thought was to transfer the original String number to Number and then divide it by 2 in BX, so the result will be in AX and remainder in DX ... but thus far i do not know how to go further, I though maybe comparing if there is 0 or 1 in the remainder area which is DX after every divide and then writing it sing by sign in new String ?

```
TITLE MASM Vstup_výstup (main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
Number DB 9 dup(?),0Dh,0Ah,§
Result DB 9 dup(?),0Dh,0Ah,§

.code
main PROC

    call Clrscr
    mov ebp, offset Number      ;first number's adress is saved to ebp
    mov esp, offset Result
    mov ecx, 20                 ;
    mov edi, 1                  ;           
    call ReadString
    mov ax, Number              ;
    sub ax, '0';                ;String to Number by substracting 0 
    mov bx, 2                   ;save 2 to 16 bit bx register
Start:  
    mov cl, [ebp+edi]           ; something as a counter to know when to end with dividing ?
    inc edi                     ; increase edi by one
    cmp cl, §                   ; compare if the counter already came here division will jump to Ending
    je Ending       
    div bx                      ; divide ax with bx, which means that result will be in AX and remainder in DX
    cmp dx,0
    je Zero                     ; if the remainder is 0 it will write 0 in the new string 
    jmp Start                   ; jmp to start

Zero:
    mov esi, [esp+edi]


Ending:

    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you're actually doing is changing a **string** which contains an ASCII representation of a decimal number into the equivalent **number** in a register.  The typical way to do this is to start with the most significant digit and repeatedly multiply the previous result by ten and add the digit's value.  In psuedo-code:

```
value = 0
for each digit, starting with the most significant:
    value = value * 10 + digitvalue
```

Comment: If you do it that way, you clearly have to start with the *most* significant digit (whatever you start with gets multiplied by 10 the most times)

Comment: @harold: oh! Thanks for pointing out that error.  I'll fix the answer.